# REST Routes with mongoose and express

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

When I try to add a review to my product from the front-end I am getting a 404 error for `PUT http://localhost:3000/products`. But I am to add/update data using the following curl command using my routes:

```
curl --data "name=Product 1&description=Product 1 Description&shine=10&price=29.95&rarity=200&color=blue&faces=3" http://localhost:3000/products
```

**My products router**

```
// This handles retrieving of products
// Includes Express
var express = require('express');
// Initialize the router
var router = express.Router();
var moment = require('moment');
var _ = require('underscore');
var color = require('cli-color');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Product = mongoose.model('Product');
var Review = mongoose.model('Review');
// Route middleware
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Something is happening in products!!");
    next();
});
// GET route for all Products
    router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
        Product.find( function (err, products) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            res.json(products);
        });
});
// POST route for adding a Product
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var product = new Product (req.body);
    product.save( function (err, post) {
        if(err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.json(product);
    });
});
// Pre-loading product object
router.param('product', function (req, res, next, id) {
    var query = Product.findById(id);
    query.exec( function (err, product) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        if(!product) {
            return next(new Error('can\'t find product'));
        }
        req.product = product;
        return next();
    })
});
// GET route for retrieving a single product
router.get('/:product', function (req, res) {
    req.product.populate('reviews', function (err, product) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
            }
        res.json(req.product);
    });
});
// POST route for creating a review
router.post('/:product:reviews', function (req, res, next) {
    var review = new Review(req.body);
    review.product = req.product;
    review.save( function (err, review){
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        req.product.reviews.push(review);
        req.product.save( function (err, review) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            res.json(review);
        });
    });
});
```

This code is taken from a tutorial on thinkster for [MEAN stackl[2](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial)

**Original Post**

I am having trouble figuring out how to update an existing entry in my *mongodb* database using a service I defined with *ngResource* in my Angular app. So far I have been unable to create a function that will update the back-end after a user clicks my submit button. I have been looking around for a solution for about 2 days but so far have not found a solution. I know the solution is similar to how I delete users in **My User's Controller**, but nothing I have tried has worked.

**My Product Service**

```
angular.module('gemStoreApp.productService',['ngResource'])
    .factory('productsService', function($resource) {
        return $resource('/products/:id', {},{
            'update': { method: 'PUT'}
        });
    });
```

**My Product Detail**

```
angular.module('gemStoreApp')
    .controller("ReviewCtrl", ['$scope', '$resource', 'productsService', function ($scope, $resource, productsService) {
        this.review = {};
        this.addReview = function(product){
            product.reviews.push(this.review);

            productService.save({id: product._id}, function() {
                // I have tried .update, .$update, and .save methods 
            });

            this.review = {};
         };
     }]);
```

I have verified that the *products.review* variable contains the update. Here is a sample of my *JSON* output from my console before and after adding the review:

*Before the review is added to the front end*

```
{"_id":"product_id","name":"Product 1","description":"Product 1 Description",...,"reviews":[{}]}
```

*After the review is added to the front end*

```
{"_id":"product_id","name":"Product 1","description":"Product 1 Description",...,"reviews":[{"stars":4,"body":"An Awesome review!","author":"user@domain.com","createdOn":1436963056994}]}
```

And I know that my *productsService.save()* function is being called as well, as I can put a console log in and see it run when I view in the browser.

**My User's Controller**

```
angular.module('gemStoreApp')
    .controller('UsersCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'usersService', function ($scope, $http, usersService) {
        $scope.users = {};
        $scope.users = usersService.query();
        $scope.remove = function(id) {
            var user = $scope.users[id];
            usersService.remove({id: user._id}, function() {
                $scope.users.splice(user, 1);
            });
        };
    }]);
```

My full source code is available on my [Github](https://github.com/herrjosua/GemStoreExpress) page. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the product object coming from ?

Comment: I assume your asking how I am getting my product object from my database? I am using mongoose and express to connect to my database. if it helps my project is based on a tutorial for Angular and Express app. And is located at: http://start.jcolemorrison.com/building-an-angular-and-express-app-part-1/

Comment: Nah just misread, anyway how (where ?) do you call your function addReview ? The point is that you should do product.$update instead of service.save(). But this will work only if your var "product" come form the $resource service.

Comment: I call the addReview function on a ng-submit on my form. Here is a snippet of my html: <form class="form-horizontal" name="reviewForm" ng-controller="ReviewCtrl as reviewCtrl" ng-submit="reviewForm.$valid && reviewCtrl.addReview(product)" novalidate>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually put it into work in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QSTJsOjggvGoBmdVpYdO?p=preview)

Took the same factory :

```
app.factory('productsService', function($resource) {
    return $resource('product/:id', {id:"@id"},{
        'update': { method: 'PUT'}
    });
});
```

here is my controller :

```
$scope.products = productsService.query();
$scope.saveProduct = function(product){
  product.$update();
}
```

and how i pass the value in the HTML :

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">
  <input type="text" ng-model="product.text"> 
  <button ng-click="saveProduct(product)">Update</button>
</div>
```

If you track the networks request in the javascript console you will see a request : PUT /product/id with the updated data.

Hope it helped. If you have anymore question fell free to ask.

Comment: I am still having issues, but now I believe the issue is with my routes on the server side. I am getting a 404 error. I will update my op with the code from my routes.

Comment: @HerrJosua You should repost with the appropriate tags then. I'm not sure that you will have any help for a sever part with only the angular tag :)